# float object is not subscribtable Sentence Transformer encode

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, cosine-similarity, sentence-transformers

I'm trying to run a function that calculates the similarity between the values in a column and all the values in a another dataframe. For some reason it keeps on giving this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 import numpy as np
      3 # Get the similarity scores between each activity in df1 and all the columns in df2
----> 4 similarity_scores = get_similarities(df, specialties_data)
      6 # Get the column with the highest similarity score for each activity in df1
      7 max_sim_col = []

Input In [24], in get_similarities(df1, df2)
      8 similarity_scores = []
      9 for activity in df1.processed_activities:
---> 10     activity_embeddings = model.encode(activity, convert_to_tensor=True)
     11     activity_similarity_scores = []
     12     for col in df2.columns:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py:161, in SentenceTransformer.encode(self, sentences, batch_size, show_progress_bar, output_value, convert_to_numpy, convert_to_tensor, device, normalize_embeddings)
    159 for start_index in trange(0, len(sentences), batch_size, desc="Batches", disable=not show_progress_bar):
    160     sentences_batch = sentences_sorted[start_index:start_index+batch_size]
--> 161     features = self.tokenize(sentences_batch)
    162     features = batch_to_device(features, device)
    164     with torch.no_grad():

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py:319, in SentenceTransformer.tokenize(self, texts)
    315 def tokenize(self, texts: Union[List[str], List[Dict], List[Tuple[str, str]]]):
    316     """
    317     Tokenizes the texts
    318     """
--> 319     return self._first_module().tokenize(texts)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py:102, in Transformer.tokenize(self, texts)
    100 batch1, batch2 = [], []
    101 for text_tuple in texts:
--> 102     batch1.append(text_tuple[0])
    103     batch2.append(text_tuple[1])
    104 to_tokenize = [batch1, batch2]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the code:

```
import torch
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2').to(device)

def get_similarities(df1, df2):
    similarity_scores = []
    for activity in df1.processed_activities:
        activity_embeddings = model.encode(activity, convert_to_tensor=True)
        activity_similarity_scores = []
        for col in df2.columns:
            col_embeddings = model.encode(str(df2[col]), convert_to_tensor=True)
            similarity = cosine_similarity(activity_embeddings.reshape(1, -1), col_embeddings.reshape(1, -1))
            activity_similarity_scores.append(similarity.item())
        similarity_scores.append(activity_similarity_scores)
    return similarity_scores

import numpy as np

# Get the similarity scores between each activity in df1 and all the columns in df2
similarity_scores = get_similarities(df, specialties_data)

# Get the column with the highest similarity score for each activity in df1
max_sim_col = []
for sim_scores in similarity_scores:
    max_sim_col.append(specialties_data.columns[np.argmax(sim_scores)])

# Add the column with the highest similarity score to df1
df['max_similarity_column'] = max_sim_col0

df.to_csv("final.csv",index=False)
print(df)
```

Not entirely sure why this error is happening if anyone can shed some light on the matter.

Comment: `activity` is not a sentence, could you print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity` variable might contain a float value which cause problem in `model.encode(activity, convert_to_tensor=True)` . Be sure that that `processed_activities` column in your df1 DataFrame only contains strings.

Something like that:

```
def get_similarities(df1, df2):
    similarity_scores = []
    for activity in df1.processed_activities:
        activity = str(activity)  # Convert activity to string
        activity_embeddings = model.encode(activity, convert_to_tensor=True)
        activity_similarity_scores = []
        for col in df2.columns:
            col_embeddings = model.encode(str(df2[col]), convert_to_tensor=True)
            similarity = cosine_similarity(activity_embeddings.reshape(1, -1), col_embeddings.reshape(1, -1))
            activity_similarity_scores.append(similarity.item())
        similarity_scores.append(activity_similarity_scores)
    return similarity_scores
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
a = 1.0
a[0]
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21292\1210706423.py in <module>
      1 a = 1.0
----> 2 a[0]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

How you can see, you try work with float object as with an iterable object.

Problem is here:

```
 10     activity_embeddings = model.encode(activity, convert_to_tensor=True)
```

I can't see what wrong with "activity" because i don't know which dataset used.

Check NaN objects

```
import numpy as np
np.nan[0]
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21292\324790454.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 np.nan[0]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

You can try something like this:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```